# How to get sticky header index on scroll in section list? - React Native

Tags: react-native, scroll, calendar, react-native-sectionlist

I wanted to access the sticky header index on scroll in the Section list. I had implemented AgendaList and I need to set the calendar date on the list scroll and the list has date sections. so when a particular section sticks, I need to access that date.